# Redirect all pages using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect the main URL of http://123.456.789/~client to http://www.newdomain.com.

However, I also need to redirect all the pages too, so for example...

http://123.456.789/~client/careers = http://www.newdomain.com/careers

http://123.456.789/~client/contact = http://www.newdomain.com/contact
...etc

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .htaccess under `~client/` directory and use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, that forwards the Home page but nowt the sub-pages. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: It should redirect everything as we are capturing `(.*)` Make sure this is first rule in `~client/.htaccess`

Comment: Ah yes, silly me! I moved it above a conflicting rule and it worked. Can't believe this was so easy. Thanks so much for pointing it out, it's much appreciated.